# Android Studio doesn't detect my connected physical devices

Tags: android-studio, mobile-devices, usb-debugging, developer-mode

The AVD Manager in Android Studio doesn't show my device but `adb devices` command in teminal shows it. How to resolve my issues ?

Comment: My device didnt show up till i plugged it in while in studio. Might have been something else though, v0.1!

Comment: Just in case somebody finds this question while having the same problem as I did: if your device isn't visible in `adb devices` either, your problem could be that you are using a USB 3 port. Lollipop can only connect if you use a USB 2 port.

Comment: Go to `Settings -> About phone -> Tap on Build number several times`, then go to `Settings -> Developer -> USB debugging`

Comment: Android studio has a Tools->Adb Connection assistant. It has helped me, maybe it will help you too. Following it is faster than reading the answers here.

Comment: You have to enable the **USB debugging** option in **Developer Options** of your phone's settings. Android Studio recognized my phone after doing this. Make sure to grant all the requested permissions that pop up on the phone's screen when you enable this option. Checkout my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58258281/10259491

Comment: In my case I just have to toggle USB Debugging to off and then on again which prompted a message and upon selecting Yes then it showed up in the Android Studio

Comment: I tried everything and in the end, I came to know that the cable borrowed from my friend to connect with ADB Wifi wasn't supportive at all. I changed the cable and it worked.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

To change what your application defaults to when you click run or debug in Android Studio, follow these steps:

**1.** go to *Run*

**2.** Click on *Edit Configurations*

**3.** Select the project

**4.** find the *Target Device* section under the *General tab* on the *Android Application page*.

That seems to be where you toggle what the project builds to. If you're importing a project it actually defaults to Emulator, not sure why. You can also select "Open Select Deployment Target Dialog" to list both connected as well as emulated devices.

Comment: I have just set my build target to USB device in the manner specified here, and then all of a sudden the IDE cannot recognise the R class.

Comment: i don't see Run -> Edit Configurations anywhere in android studio... screenshot?

Comment: I followed these steps, and when I selected the usb device, a popup said it needed to install Android 1.0 because that it the target OS. However, my phone and an HTC One M8 and I was able to debug on it last week. Something changed that is now causing Abdroid Studio to fail to see my phone as a viable debugging device. I tried it on another computer running Android Studio and it worked fine. So there must be some other setting or maybe even a driver someplace that is causing this.

Comment: I followed these steps, but when I try to run I get: "Error running app: No target device found"

Comment: Funny coincidence, but I also am seeing the exact same problem on my HTC One M(8): used to be able to load the app onto it, but no longer.

Comment: try installing PADNet++, It'll surely resolve this issue.

Comment: For those that tried this and thought it didn't work - are you looking in "Tools" -> "AVD Manager"? If so, you need to do the steps described above and then run the project as normal. You should see it on the "Select Deployment Target" under "Connected Devices"

Comment: But why dont the selection dialog shows the devices? If I run `adb devices` in the command line, it is connected properly.

Comment: On Android 11 the path to activate developer options is different: Info zu Tablet -> Softwareinformationen -> 7 x Buildnummer

Answer (score 401):

I recently had trouble with this, and regardless of what I did(restart adb, edit adb_usb.ini, restart computer+device+swap usb port, reinstall studio etc. etc.) I just couldnt get it to work, and could not even detect my device using 'adb devices'. Finally after about 2  hours of googling and testing, someone suggested switching to **PTP** instead of **MTP** on my device. When I did this I got a popup on my device asking me to allow my mac access and suddenly everything worked(had to restart studio for it to show up there as well though).

I might be bumping this thread now, but it is the first result on google search, and I had a lot of trouble finding an answer for this problem, so I thought this should be added as a solution.

Comment: turning PTP or MTP on if off, or off if it is on triggers a popup, then suddenly everything works.  i do not know why i need to toggle PTP or MTP for android studio to recognize my device.  to set PTP or MTP -> "Modern Android devices use the MTP or PTP protocols — you can choose which one you prefer.  To select a USB connection protocol, open the Settings app, tap Storage, tap the menu button, and tap USB computer connection. "  http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/  (thank you LGBo)

Comment: @Suspended PTP = connect as camera, MTP = connect as media device. You should be able to do a web search if you want to know more.

Comment: the reason why it worked when you switched to `PTP` is that the first time you ran it, you did't authorize USB debugging from the dialog on your phone. if you want to use `MTP` try revoking USB authorization from **settings -> developer options -> revok usb authorization** then start over.

Comment: What does it mean when the USB device is not recognized on certain projects within AS but is recognized on others?

Comment: When I upgraded to Android 8.1, I suddenly started having this issue. Following the instructions provided by @tmr resolved the issue for me!

Comment: That worked fine, thank you! In my case, I have Windows 10 laptop and LG Stylo 5. I chose pop up option of "MIDI" on a phone after connecting it to laptop (instead of "Storage")

Comment: God bless you! No words can show my appraciation for how much this answer helped me.

Comment: This answer helped me, not exactly like it says but on my phone it was set to "No file transfer" by default and the option to change it to MTP was burried pretty deep, a notification would be nice, Motorola!

Comment: I tried everything and in the end, I came to know that the cable borrowed from my friend to connect with ADB Wifi wasn't supportive at all. I changed the cable and it worked.

Comment: For me it was easier I just started to read through this stackoverflow thread and then magically popup appeared :)

Answer (score 326):

**On your device:**

> Go to settings/ developer settings/ allow USB debug mode

If 'allow USB debug mode' option is disabled. Then you might have the device currently connected to your PC. Disconnect the device and the option should now be available

**Note:** On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

If it still doesn't help, you can google it with this expression:

> How to enable developer options on YOUR_PHONE_TYPE

Just in case it saves anyone 5 minutes of head-scratching, 'Developer options' is now under 'Settings/System & updates/Developer options'

Comment: From the android docs: `Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.` https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#setting-up

Comment: Other answers didn't work, but it was as simple as this!

Comment: My USB debug mode got disabled somehow. Perhaps from a software update. So don't overlook checking if USB debug mode is enabled, even if you enabled it before.

Comment: Even if debug mode is enabled try to refresh it switching on and off owrked for me ;)

Comment: Just in case it saves anyone 5 minutes of head-scratching, 'Developer options' is now under 'Settings/System & updates/Developer options'

Answer (score 131):

**Some cables can not been used for developer mode or transfer file**. A solution would be change your cable and don't waste time.

[Trendblog post](http://trendblog.net/android-file-transfer-not-working/)

**Edited**

Some USB3 ports are causing issues too. Not sure if there is a way to check if the cable/usb works. But there is a way to detect the USB type [USB2 or USB3?](https://superuser.com/questions/756669/how-to-detect-if-a-usb-port-is-3-0-or-2-0) . If you are using USB3 could be a port issue too.

Comment: I had a cable that used to work for 10 months with Android Studio.  It STILL works for charging but will no longer show as a 'connected device' in Android Studio!

Comment: The garbage cable that came our multi-phone charging station was the problem. The official Samsung one that came with the phone works great.

Comment: All was fine last week, but now cable from multi-usb port stopped working. I can use same cable plugged directly into Mac USB-C -> Digital AV adaptor to see device.

Comment: If you've tried everything else and still can't deploy, this is probably the issue.

Comment: This worked for me. Although `adb devices` shown that my device was still attached, Android Studio couldn't run on my phone until I changed the cable.

Comment: Not my cable, but my **USB3** port didn't seem to work for ADB, switched to a **USB2** and it was fine.

Comment: Is it possible to test the cable somehow? So that I can now if my cable is the problem. The cable the came with my new phone only has USB-C connectors in both ends, that I can't use with my PC's USB-A ports...

Comment: For me, it turned out that the device was not detected when connected to my laptop via a USB hub. When I connected the device directly to a USB port on the laptop, everything started working!

Comment: In my case USb3.0 Port causing an issue.

Comment: Funny thing is yesterday the same cable was working just fine and today ... not so much... that's strange.

Comment: Having a better usb cable worked for me.

Answer (score 64):

I had to `killall adb` because somehow, Android Studio managed to crash and did not want to communicate with adb anymore. Thus, my device did not show up.

So quitting Android Studio, terminating all adb instances in Terminal and starting Android Studio again (should ask if it should enable debugging then) worked.

Comment: sometimes using activity window (mac) to kill (force quit) adb is enough (without quiting android studio).  i force quit adb, run app again via android studio, and android studio can see the mobile phone/usb device. (thanks Sebastian Wramba)

Comment: activity window (mac) to kill (force quit) adb solved it for me, thanks a lot

Comment: Fixed my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 58):

After spending some time I found the problem was to enable USB debugging option to on. Just find in your mobile Settings->Developer Option->USB debugging. Just enable it and it works.
It might help someone!

[image]

In case you do not see the Developer Option then try to enable it first:
Depending on your device and operating system, you may need to go to "Settings -> About Device or About Phone -> Software Information", then tap "Build number" seven times.

Comment: On Android 5.1, Settings->Developer Option->USB debugging has a checkbox, but it is grayed out and cannot be selected. Further down there is an option to "Select debug app" which says "No debug application set".  What is a good debug app to install and use?

Comment: @PhilGoetz just check if "Developer options" is on or not. added image for your reference.

Comment: I had to turn off USB debugging and turn it back on again.

Answer (score 40):

It works for me by following steps below:-

If you using Windows, the device won't show up because of driver issue.

Go to device manager (just search it using Start)
and look for any devices showing an error. Many androids will show as an unknown USB device and comes with exclamation mark. Select that device and try to update the drivers for it. for update part follow the link:[universal adb](http://universal-adb-driver.en.malavida.com/)

But before that, you have to update your sdk manager and make sure Google USB Driver package is installed.

When done, the driver files are downloaded into the \extras\google\usb_driver\ directory. **Hints**: Search "android_winusb.inf" under Windows Start and Open File Location to get the directory mentioned.

Open up your device manager, navigate to your android device, right click on it and select Update Driver Software then select Browse driver software. Follow the file location path previously to install Google USB Driver.

Restart Android Studio and Developer Options in your android device and reconnect USB.

Cheers !

Comment: Hey William, I tried your steps but got this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884361/cant-find-device?noredirect=1#comment55533170_33884361

Comment: What could the solution be? Thanks

Comment: Another handy program to start recognizing the device is http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver

Comment: What do you do if it's not listed in Device Manager at all? It is charging.

Comment: His device shows up in ADB.  Mine does too.  We can adb shell and transfer files to and from it. That all works and is not related to the question. -- The question is why can't android studio see it.

Answer (score 36):

In my case the following steps helped to resolve the issue:

1) Ensure the package "Google USB Driver" is installed in Android SDK Manager

2) Download "ADB Driver Installer 2.0" from [here](http://dl.adbdriver.com/upload/adbdriver.zip)

3) Run the tool downloaded and connect your smartphone; in my case it showed that the driver had been installed incorrectly and suggested to fix it

After those steps my Android Studio instantly recognised the device! Both MTP and PTP started to work.

---

Tested for Samsung (Android 4.1.2) and Xiaomi MI4W (Android 4.4.4)

Comment: Tested and works for Android 5.1. I hate Windows btw

Answer (score 29):

My Nexus 5 phone did not have developer options in the settings menu. I had to do the following:

On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Answer (score 20):

**In my case**

android studio suddenly stop seeing my device

I fix it by change **USB option**  to Media device (MTP)

how to get USB option from storage USB Computer Connection

[image]

check **Debugging** from **developer options**

try re-run on device , it should work

> issue

USB option was charge only

**UPDATE ANSWER 26/7/2016**

there many reasons like not enabling developer mode --> USB debugging(if you dont see developer option click 7 times at build number )

but I face another issue every thing was works just fine suddenly android studio cant see my device

to fix this issue you need to restart adb , from terminal

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

or from ddms

in devices section --> click at small arrow down --> restart adb

[image: ()]

Comment: found `adb reconnect` also kicked mine into action.

Answer (score 15):

I plugged my phone in and it was detected fine (no need for device manager or anything like that).. but Android Studio wasn't seeing it.

I found it takes two requirements to be met

```
- PTP (not MTP)
- USB Debugging mode on
```

For PTP , go to settings..storage..usb connection..PTP  (For MTP/PTP , maybe on my nexus it's there, but on my doogee I see it under 'developer options' .. then under networking , above input, it says "select usb configuration")

For USB debugging, settings..about..tap build about 7 times, then a new option appears for usb debugging and you can turn it on.

**Added**  this is also relevant for USB debugging or MTP/PTP being moved https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213059/where-is-the-mtp-and-ptp-option-in-android-9

Comment: PTP worked for me where MTP didn't (with Android Studio 3.2). I also made sure i had up to date 'SDK tools'

Comment: I am just extending the answer that if your don't found `PPT` option then select `MIDI` option. It's working for me.

Comment: @Ninja there's MTP, PTP, and there's MIDI.  No PPT!  https://gadgetguideonline.com/android/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2016/04/USB_options_in_Android_Marshmallow_developer_options_USB_options.jpg     MTP and PTP have been around for a while. And who is going to not find the PTP option if it is in the same menu as the (possibly more recent new) option you speak of MIDI ?

Answer (score 12):

Try the following solutions (for Windows):

- Go to your sdk tool installation path, and under \sdk\platform-tools folder and run this command:

  adb devices

If your device it listed it should show something like this:

```
C:\android\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
081e96500591f039        device
```

If not, follow this:

- Try these commands:

  adb kill-server

  adb start-server
- Make sure your phone has Developer Options in Settings (if not, go to Settings, About phone (or device), click on Android Version multiple times until you see a message).
- Make sure USB debugging on your phone is enabled (go to Developer Options in Settings and turn it on)
- Make sure you have Select USB Configuration set to MTP (this is also in Developer Options).
- Make sure you can see your files in your device in Windows Explorer when you connect via USB.
- Make sure you have the driver for your device properly installed (most of the time, this happens when you first plug in your USB cable).
- In Windows, right click on Computer, and go to Device Manager, check if you have Android Device right on the root folder and under it should be Android Composite ADB Interface. If you don't have this, you have to download the Google USB Driver. Get it here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

- In Device Manager, find your device (should have yellow Exclamation point), right click, and update driver (open the folder with the driver you just downloaded)
- If this doesn't work, try restarting Android Studio or plugging your device back in again.

Some cheap devices (some $30 tablets) don't provide the USB drivers to connect in Device Manager, so in this case you are out of luck.

Comment: Exactly. Worked for me. I have Win10. Android SDK on Win10 is here:
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`. 
Drivers are here: `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

Comment: Running `adb devices` from shell fixed it for me, because it is able to detect and fix that **the ADB daemon was not running**.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, enabling `USB Debugging` in `Developer Options` solved the problem. Make sure to grant required permissions upon reconnecting the phone.

**Enabling Developer Options**

`Phone settings >> About Phone >> Software Information >> tap Build Number repeatedly.`

**Optional Steps**

Sometimes, the phone is not detected even with `USB Debugging` on. In this case, tap on `Revoke USB debugging authorizations` in `Developer options`. Grant the required permissions on reconnecting the phone.

If it's still not being detected, then toggle `USB debugging` off and on then grant permissions upon phone reconnection.

Answer (score 10):

I have found that what works for me is:

- `CD` to your sdk platform-tools folder
- Check if adb sees your device

  ```
  ./adb devices
  ```
- If it displays 'List of devices attached' and a blank line below, then restart adb as follows:

  ```
  ./adb kill-server
  ./adb start-server
  ```

  then re-run `./adb devices` and see if it picks up the device, eg as follows:

  > List of devices attached
  >   015d2bc285601c0a device

Comment: still device not display,every time blank list

Comment: @bhoomika do you have adb interface installed in device manager? or is it showing as a yellow exclamation mark under other devices?

Answer (score 9):

UPDATE 2020 Nov 27

One more reason is your cable which might be broken (only charging is available but not debugging). Hence, buy a new one! ^^

---

Known that *"Can't connect a device with Android Studio"* is such an annoying issue to newbies, but I'm kind of an old hand at Android for a quite long time. Most of the common methods have been tried:

- How to **turn on developer mode**.
- Forgot to **enable USB debugging**.
- Sometimes need to **switch USB configuration to Transfer Files**.
- Some subliminal guides on **adb commands**, which I've never tried, though.
- Try a **new cable**.
  ...

HOWEVER, what works for me is to **REVOKE ACCESS again** for the computer your device will connect to, namely:

1. Go to Developer options.
2. Revoke USB debugging authorization.
3. Wait a bit for a dialogue to show up and ask your access consent.
4. Bang, there you go, your device is listed in Android Studio.

Comment: The enabled USB debugging helped me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

### If your phone was working previously

Before you do anything complicated, this might be a simple problem. **Just unplug and plug back in.**

### If there are additional issues

You also might want to check that your configuration is set up to launch to your phone.

**run --> edit configurations**

[image]

And make sure that you either default to the USB device or the chooser dialog if you are going to be switching between devices on your emulator as well.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, since adb devices show the device.

Comment: It's pretty insane that FIVE YEARS later, this bug still exists. Just had this exact problem

Answer (score 8):

Be sure that you have downloaded the correct API for the version you device is using. After updating your device's Android version or switching to a different device you may not have the correct API downloaded on Android Studio. To do this:

1. Check your devices Android OS version by going to Settings>About Phone>Android Version
2. Make sure you have the correct API installed in Android Studio in the SDK Manager

Comment: The question had already a valid answer accepted by the question owner.

Comment: Does not always help. I have a phone with Android 4.3, I installed it in SDK manager, the phone device still doesn't show up when running the app.

Answer (score 8):

Also try uncheck "Tools" - "Android" - "Enable ADB Integration".

This is work for me after update Windows to 10.

Comment: Hey, I am having this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884361/cant-find-device?noredirect=1#comment55533170_33884361

Comment: Great insight! Didn't know about this option. ADB was working for me, but Android Studio wasn't. FYI for visitors from the future, I'm on Linux.

Comment: I had this issue on Mac and this suggestion solved it!

Comment: This worked with me as well on Debian and Genymotion

Comment: This setting is now enabled by default and is now "Use libusb backend". This managed to uncheck itself in Android Studio. I re-enabled it following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372572/where-is-enable-adb-integration-option-in-android-studio-3-3).

Answer (score 6):

This helped me. I followed the instructions on the "***Troubleshoot Device Connections"*** located on the AVD Manager Devices dropdown:

1. Make sure your Android phone is connected via USB to your computer
2. Go to your Android phone
3. Go to **Settings > About phone > Software information** on your phone
4. Tap **Build number** seven times
5. **Developer** option is now enabled in your phone
6. Go to **Developer**
7. Turn on or enable **USB debugging**
8. Allow computer access to phone
9. Now click on ***"Troubleshoot Device Connections"***
10. Click Next until you reach ***"Restart ADB Server"***. Click on that and restart

Your device should now show on the AVD Manager dropdown list.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Please check debug mode in device]

[image: Config same image]

After u turn on debug mode open settings/Developer options
Update config same image

Comment: And make sure USB Debugging is turned on/checked

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had to set up my android to `enable USB debugging`.

[image]

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#setting-up

Answer (score 4):

The AVD Manager is for emulator images. It never shows hardware. This is true for any usage of the AVD Manager: Eclipse, Android Studio, etc.

Comment: Ok how do I get android studio to run the app on the phone then?

Comment: @amnesyc, you have to have debugging turned on inside your device

Answer (score 4):

If you still have this problem (later than summer 2015) maybe you should:

1. Go here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top
2. Download the driver
3. Reinstall it

I recently installed Windows 10 (not an upgrade, a clean installation) and I forgot the ADB USB driver

Comment: This worked for me after trying all other options. Thought my new install of Win 10 may have done it

Answer (score 4):

Try changing mode of usb connection to midi devices. Thats what worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

When I faced this problem I was on Android Studio 3.1 version. I tried a lot of approach above, nothing worked for me ( Don't know why **:/** ). Finally I tried something different by my own. My approach was:

Before going to bellow steps make sure

```
*Your "Google USB Driver" package is installed ("Tools" -> "SDK Manager" -> Check "Google USB Driver" -> "Apply" -> "Ok").

*If you are trying to access with emulator then check "Intel x86 Emulator Accelarator(HAXM installer)" is instaled. ("Tools" -> "SDK Manager" -> Check "Intel x86 Emulator Accelarator(HAXM installer)"" -> "Apply" -> "Ok")
```

1. Goto **Tools**.
2. Then goto **SDK Manager**.
3. Open **SDK tools**.
4. *Uncheck*  "**Android SDK Platform-Tools**" (On my case it was checked).
5. press **apply** then **ok**.
6. Again goto **Tools**.
7. Then goto **SDK Manager**.
8. Open **SDK tools**.
9. *check*  "**Android SDK Platform-Tools**"
10. Restart Android Studio :)

Hope this will help somebody like me.

Answer (score 4):

if your device version in 9 then

Go to SDK Tools and Update Sdk same Version and **Intstall Google USB Driver**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Turn on USB debugging and connect the device to PC. Wait until the device gets detected by PC. While connected, turn off USB debugging and turn on it again.

Answer (score 4):

**while doing all this don't forget to increase the sleep time, so that if the device prompts for authentication on the mobile device you know that the connection is succeeded.**

**Try 1:**

1. Install "microsoft universal c runtime".
2. Download the file as per your OS (operating system.)
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Installing Google USB Driver from Developersdeveloper.android.com didn't work for me.
[image]
**Try 2:**

1. search "androidmtk" and install driver installer. (restart pc) (check whether device is showing)
2. Else search "adbdriver" and install driver installer. (restart pc) (check whether device is showing)

**Try 3:**

- Check out whether in Android studio's status bar (displayed at the very bottom of window), any message has been shown. Do the changes suggested in the message.

**Try 4:**

- Check whether device is shown after changing the connection type (mostly shown on dragging the top bar on home screen).
- i.e. "Charging only", "Transfer files", "Transfer photos PTP or MTP"

**Try 5:**

- Go to Android "Tools menu"->"SDK manager"->
- Below "Android SDK location" you will see 3 tabs.
- Out of it click on "SDK tools" and in the list find and tick-mark "Google USB drivers" and install the package.
- Restart the computer.

Answer (score 3):

I know it sounds crazy but i just reboot my phone while was connected and it appears

Answer (score 3):

If you use Samsung you can [download](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/app/smart-switch) and install the device driver from Samsung.

Note

1. You need to enable ADB mode(Like the eleventh comment)
2. You need to set Target in Android Studio to "Open Select Deployment Target" Dialog. To set Target : Run > Edit Configurations > Targets > Open Select Deployment Target Dialog

Answer (score 3):

I am using Android Studio 4.0, Android Studio said "Device was detected by ADB but not Android Studio". I tried re-enable "developer option" and "usb debug", re-plugin the usb, but no luck. I restart the Android Studio and it works.

**Please try restart the Android Studio.**

Hope it could save you some time.

Answer (score 3):

If your device was working with Android Studio before this issue, then restarting the device can solve the problem.

**Make sure to turn on USB Debugging from Developer Options again after restarting.**

Answer (score 2):

I have been troubleshotting same problem. 
I have tried all the tips in this topic in posts above me.

My situation was:
- computer have seen my tablet
- had debug usb options in developer mode on
- adb in sdk was not seeing my device, killing & start didnt help

The problem was I had Samsung Galaxy drivers on my win8. When I went to devices manager, there was Lenovo A7600 Tablet with yellow marking. Settings -> actualize drivers -> choose from existing ones and i hooked up the Samsung drivers to this one.

It worked like charm.

Comment: Thanks dude, It worked on my galaxy s7 edge. All I had to do was, just like u said, update through device manager my drivers manually. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If every configuration is sorted, what worked for me was to switch the device to be connected at `PTP` and then back to `MTP`.

Answer (score 2):

Switching to PTP USP Option instead of MTP is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

None of above answers solved my problem until I updated SDK platform-tools.This maybe one of the causes of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Android version of Nougat API 24, I solved a device problem not detected by replacing the USB cable.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why Android Studio doesn't see mobile phone.

One of them is a problem with **ADB Interface driver**. You can check it in your Device Manager:

[image]

If you don't have ADB Interface driver, then use this guide to install it for Intel chipset: [Installing the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) USB Driver on a Windows Computer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/installing-android-debug-bridge-adb-usb-driver-on-windows).

If you have other, but not Intel, then try to search for the driver on manufacture's web-site.

For **Xiaomi** phones, turn off **MIUI optimization** in the very bottom of *Developers mode* menu.

Answer (score 1):

Check device driver
if your device is Galaxy install Kise will search your driver

Answer (score 1):

As driver was unable to load, I was unable to connect to my device on windows 7.  I followed the steps below:

1. Download Android USB driver from [Intel site](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-android-usb-driver)
2. Install the driver and reboot your system
3. Connect your device and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly enough, what worked for me on Debian Linux was ONLY:

```
adb kill-server
```

WITHOUT STARTING IT AGAIN!!!

The device appeared in the Android Studio as soon as I killed the server. The only reason I spotted this was that my terminal emulator window was transparent. :D

Answer (score 1):

For Samsung Galaxy s4 i resolved issue by instaling Kies software, after that everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Turned out to be a faulty data cable. The device would start charging but would not show up in connected devices in Android Studio.

Trying another cable worked fine.

Try another cable first if you have been using your current one for a while.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to fix USB driver on your computer.
Start -> Device Manger -> Other devices.
Right click on the USB device then Update Driver Software -> Browse my Computer ..-> Let me pick... -> Android device -> Next.

Answer (score 1):

So I am using Android Studio 3.1 and nothing above worked. The only thing that fixed the problem is enabling the checkbox of "Use libusb backend" See attached [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's my first time running Android project today through Android Studio since its 2.x version, and I have the same problem. However, this is with the Flutter plugin. I have a workaround for people with similar setup.

My setup:

- macOS Mojave on MacBook with Type-C-to-USB dongle
- Android 6.0
- Android Studio 3.4.1: Android SDK 9.+, 6.0
- On Mac, `ANDROID_HOME` is defined, `PATH` includes all the required tool paths

Observation

- `adb devices` gives the correct device info;
- `flutter devices` shows correct device info with more details;
- Android Studio's Connection Assistant shows `Android` as detected USB device;
- **Toolbar shows `<no devices>`**;
- **AVD manager shows no such a device**.

My workaround

- Open Terminal and `cd` to my project root;
- Run `flutter run` and the app is correctly deployed and runs fine;

After that, my observation

- Toolbar shows my device name; I can then run everything from toolbar directly, including Hot Reload;
- USB config on my device automatically switches to PTP from the default MTP;
- **AVD Manager still does not show my device**. Shame!

But at least I'm no longer blocked.

Reference:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1525

Answer (score 1):

Especially if you had a connection previously, if you are using some other application that used ADB connection to your phone - close that application. I have Total Commander that has plugin for ADB connection to mobile phone, and that solved my problem.

Comment: This was it for me. Had `logkitty` running, as soon as I closed it Android Studio picked up my phone, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, Macbook USB C Hub was the issue. I connected the phone directly to Mac USB C port and worked like charm! hope this help!

Comment: damn. you’re  right. USB hub was causing issue

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps to solve above issue.

1. Right click on `Project`
2. select `"Create Run Configurations"`
3. `All tests`. (second option)
4. in `General` Tab --> `Target device`

Comment: Not in eclipse.. question related to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In my case, and I know this is dumb, but here's what I had to do.

I had tried all the solutions above and none worked. A good key to t-shooting is when `adb devices` won't list the device, then you know you aren't cooking with gas yet.

Switching between USB modes won't have an effect until the device registers as a device over adb. You'll know when that happens because you'll get a prompt about an RSA key.

It was a relatively new install of Windows 7. Under USB in my phone's notification area, I switched to **Install Driver** and let it install my adb driver. In my case I was never going to get anything legit over the internet.

Once I saw that successfully install, I switched to PTP and it all just worked.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio did not show my device (Samsung Galaxy Alpha) on Windows too until I downloaded and installed a Windows driver from Samsung Support page. I had to use the MTP connection mode on the device. I also confirmed authorizing the computer after I connected the device to it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.
After looking though my edge 6 the enable usb debugging was greyed out and unable to be turned on.
Quick google search showed it was the myKnox security program that was stopping this from being used. all you need to do is uninstall myKnox and you can then allow usb debugging. This solved my problem with the choose device dialog now showing my connected phone.

Answer (score 0):

Update last usb driver

[Install the Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.htm)

1. In Android Studio, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager.
2. Click the SDK Tools tab.
3. Select Google USB Driver package and click Install.
4. Proceed to install the package. When done, the driver files are downloaded into the \extras\google\usb_driver\ directory.

Comment: Google USB driver is not compatible with Mac

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this question is still open. But I solved the issue by switching to a different usb cable. hopefully, this can save you a couple hours. lol

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone having problem with Samsung GT-I9060 I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509422/android-device-is-not-connected-to-usb-for-debugging-android-studio) on SO:

> If you are on windows, many times it will not recognize the device
>   fully and because of driver issues, the device won't show up.
>
> 1. go to settings
> 2. control panel
> 3. hardware and sound
> 4. device manager
>
> And look for any devices showing an error. Many androids will show as
>   an unknown USB device. Select that device and try to update the
>   drivers for it.

I uninstalled the device, unplug the device and plug it again. This time Windows properly installed the driver. What a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

if your Windows cannot even install the driver, you should go to Device Manager and get the Device ID (right click on your device->Properties->Details->Hardware Ids (in Property).
Install the Google USB drivers from Android Studio.
Go to android_winusb.inf file (under ANDROID_SDK_DIR/extras/google/usb_driver/) and add your Device ID according to the file format.
Run "adb devices" again and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/ as this worked well for me. Had to download and install the USB drivers inside Android studio then actually install the drivers via device manager  in windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this might be useful for someone out there. 
In my case I am running Android Studio in a mac and also trying Visual Studio Xamarin. Having both of them opened at the same time was creating this conflict. So closing Visual was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers already but I had just downloaded a simulator running O, and after that no device ever worked again. I deleted the emulator from AVD manager killed adb and then restarted Android studio. Moved the USB to another port and the device was there again.

Answer (score 0):

After updating to **Android Studio 3.1**, it stopped seeing my devices, but `adb` saw them fine.

To resolve this, you need to start debugging with an emulator once and after that switch back to `USB Device` in `Run` -> `Edit configurations...` -> `Target`. This time it should work.

There are a lot of changes in Android Studio 3.1 vs its previous versions, so you have to kinda reset debug target in order to make your devices work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to close to restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In my case There was multiple instance of adb got created. Unplug device from system.
Open Task Monitor (Activity Monitor) and check for adb instances. Kill all adb processes. Try to connect device again. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

Since no-one else seems to have mentioned this, I had this problem on Windows 10 and fixed it:

- by ensuring that `ANDROID_HOME` was set in the system environments variables and then restarting Android Studio (you may have to log out and log in again / restart explorer.exe).
- possibly unrelated, but on Windows 10 ensure that the telnet client via Start -> 'features'

Answer (score 0):

Env - AS 3.3.2 
      Linux 4 (ubuntu)

```
in AS used menu Tools > Create desktop entry
```

Desktop file content -  ( note the path does NOT include Platform-tools )

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Icon=jetbrains-studio.png
Path=/home/rob/android-studio
Exec=sh -c ' /home/rob/android-studio/bin/studio.sh' 
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

Note that the location of SDK.platform-tools 'adb' below will not be found by desktop.PATH above:

```
 $ which adb
/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb
```

On my setup, my symptom was that any terminal would list the device OK but the toolbar button in AS would never show a connected device...  "no devices" is all i would ever see when my phone was connected via USB cable.

SOLUTION for me was adding the correct PATH near the top of the file:

```
 ${AS_HOME}/bin/studio.sh ...

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 , the only thing that worked for me is this.
Go to Device Manager -> Under Android Phone -> Right Click and select 'enable'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My setup

- Android Studio 3.5.3
- macOS 10.14.6
- Android 9 device is connected to Mac with a Belkin USB hub.

When running a Kotlin sample project from Google's Android github repo, there is no configuration, nor devices showing up in the UI.

### Solution

- `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files`
- But my internet connection needs a fix, so I had to go to `Preferences > System Settings > HTTP Proxy` to specify a working proxy.
- Make sure `buildscript{ ext.kotlin_version }` runs a more recent version. I had to upgrade it from 1.2.xx to 1.3.xx.
- Now the project appears to be ready to build (the default emulator Nexus config is now enabled). Rebuild the project for the emulator just to make sure.
- Then I had to unplug my device from the USB hub and connect it to Mac directly. Now Android Studio sees my device.
- Plug the device again into the USB hub. Now Android Studio sees my device with the hub, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had usb to usbc hub on my macbook pro which was blocking the device somehow, it worked when I connected it directly with the apple usbc to usb dongle.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced this issue with my new allotted PC by my company That is a Lenovo L450 (with Windows 10 installed) and I am not able to connect my phone (Redmi note3) to use for debugging purpose. My Android device is working fine with my other PC for debugging purpose.

I also tried commands related to the **adb** and I try to find all possible solutions. Then I go for YouTube help and this video is very useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KdH4j7aAPM

Answer (score 0):

Thing which worked for me is is to uncheck the usb debug mode under your mobile setting 
developer option  and allow again it will
show the my device option

Comment: You need to provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

- windows 10.
- Android Studio 4.1 .
- Samsung galaxy a50.

In Android Studio do this:
File – settings – languages and frameworks – flutter .
Then point to the spot in your computer where you flutter is stored at, like:
C:\Desktop\Flutter for example.

Hope it helps. : D

Answer (score 0):

try the following command and reconnect your device, it will show up.

```html
adb kill-server
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced same problem in windows 8 and found the solution.

1) Right click on My Computer.
2) Click on manager.
3) Go to Device Manager.
4) Right click on device name (Which below on Other devices).
5) Click on Update Driver.
6) Click on next.
7) Click on Let me know... label.

Driver will be installed automatically.

Its works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have done numerous ways of handling that issue. Here is the flavor of what you need to follow step by step. I hope it would help you out.

**Step 1:** Make sure your device is enabled for development.

**Step 2:** Before you plug your device to PC, make sure you select `USB Connection method`.

**Step 3:** When you plug the phone in, you are given options for the USB Connection method, select `Internet connection`. Make sure you have connected to the Internet.

**Step 4:** Run the app in the `Android Studio`, it will ask you to authorize the device for development, and select YES.

**Step 5:** Run the application via `Android Studio` and choose the device, not emulator, and BINGO! Welcome to Android development board.

Comment: With the Verizon LG prepaid, piece of crap, phone, you have to do this and after internet connection it will ask you to select ethernet or modem. Just select ethernet. Although, I read either will work.

Comment: Yes I have just bought that device to play with Android Studio and it gave me hard time to figure that out.