# Android device is not connected to USB for debugging (Android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb

I am trying to debug my application using a real device instead on the emulator. When I try to connect, it gives me the message:

> USB device not found

I tried to unplug and plug it again, but it did not work. And I have also enabled *USB debugging* and *unknown sources options* in my device.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: restart android studio when device connected to pc

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It did not work. Still gives me that message !

Comment: I use OnePlus One phone for debugging. When I connected Samsung Tab and debuged my app on it, suddenly I could not debug with OPO again. I dont know how this is possible but when I checked on OPO Developer options, Android debugging switch was off.

Comment: The following answer helped me solve the problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225927/android-studio-doesnt-list-my-phone-under-choose-device/38801761#38801761

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you are on windows, many times it will not recognize the device fully and because of driver issues, the device won't show up.

- go to settings
- control panel
- hardware and sound
- device manager

And look for any devices showing an error.
Many androids will show as an unknown USB device.
Select that device and try to update the drivers for it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. When I go to devices. Under Other devices it showed the Android Adapter with an exclamation mark. But when I try to update that. Update fails.

Comment: Great thnaks. I downloaded the device USB drivers separately from manufactures website. Now I can connect to the device.

Comment: Thanks alot. But I have to do more steps as @parsley72's advice:http://stackoverflow.com/a/19461399/3686940

Comment: Thanks, this worked for an LG K7 that Walmart sells. I installed LG's drivers, and then it worked.

Comment: Welp, I actually enabled and disabled the listed usb adapter for android in the device manager. And holy moly it's working! :D

Comment: download latest download latest usb driver for windows from this link: [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html)

then open device manager > select your device and update drivers

Answer (score 125):

I had this problem with a Nexus 7 - it appeared in Device Manager fine but wasn't recognised by Android Studio. The device had USB debugging turned on. Eventually I noticed an icon in the top left hand corner that said "Connected as a media device. Touch for other USB options." When I selected this I was able to change from Media Device (MTP) to Camera (PTP) and then it started working.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to restart Android Studio.

Comment: Worked for me too. Changing to PTP and restaring android studio

Comment: Worked for me. Changing the from MTP and PTP, disconnecting and reconnecting the cable to the device did it.

Comment: @parsley72 You save my life sir. I select Camera (PTP) device then it found my device. My device is Walton primo RX4

Comment: Actually I was having issue for the tablets other smartphones were working properly. MTP to PTP solved my issue.

Comment: Selecting 'Photos' mode on my Huawei phone worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

This solution works for every unrecognized android device... mostly general brands don´t come with usb debugging drivers...

- go to settings
- control panel
- hardware and sound
- device manager
- And look for any devices showing an error. Many androids will show as
  an unknown USB device or just Android

First thing you need will be your device IDs.  You can get them opening up the device manager and finding the "Unknown Device" with a yellow exclamation point.  Right click on it and select 'Properties', and then go to the 'Details' tab.  Under the 'Property' drop down menu, select hardware IDs.  There should be two strings:

```
USB\VID_2207&PID_0011&REV_0222&MI_01
USB\VID_2207&PID_0011&MI_01
```

Copy those strings somewhere and then navigate to where you downloaded the Google USB driver.  Then you need to open up the file 'android_winusb.inf' in a text editor.  I would recommend using Notepad++.

[image: android_winusb.inf]

First, create a sub-section for your device.  I called mine ';RCA 6378W2' but it doesn't really matter what you call it.  Then, under the sub-section you created paste the Device ID strings you copied from the Device Manager, preceded by '%SingleAdbInterface%'.  If you need help, look at this screenshot.

**NOTE:**

If you are using Windows 8 or 8.1, you will need to disable device driver signature checks before you'll be able to install the modified driver. Here's a quick video on how to disable device driver checks http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NM1MN8QZhnk.  Ignore the part at the beginning about 64 bit, your computer architecture doesn't matter.

[Please look at this article, for more information and MacOS instructions.](http://ryancuda.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/how-to-get-working-adb-drivers-for.html)

Comment: Thanks! Helps for Samsung Galaxy Star GT-S7262. I added this section to android_winusb.inf file - `;Samsung Galaxy Star
%SingleAdbInterface%  = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6866&REV_0400&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%  = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6866&MI_01`

Comment: Mine just says unknown.

Comment: Helped me with a Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016).

Answer (score 11):

Try a different cable, ideally an official Samsung one.

I had tried a crappy USB cable I had lying around and then tried another which was Samsung and works perfectly now.

Not sure why they would be different though but worked for me.

Comment: This happened to be my issue. It's kind of awkward that I can charge my phone with this USB cable, but I cannot use it to transfer data. I guess, it's an USB 1.0/1.1 cable.

Comment: This response should be substantially upvoted. It has happened to me many times, and even the good cables you buy wear out over repeated use. Unless it's some weird windows USB thing (I'm on Linux with udev) -- and NOTHING ELSE WORKS -- it's the f***king gd$mn usb cable connector. Guaranteed, every time.

Answer (score 6):

Found out for Samsung, Installing Kies also update the usb driver which solve my problem with connecting my Samsung Galaxy S Advance with Android 4.1.2 to Android Studio on Windows 7 64bit.
In this case the devise manager shows device driver is updated and working, but when I connect my phone Android Studio does not recognize my device.

Comment: I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite and could not connect to a Galaxy S7. After trying Samsung Kies, I did get a new prompt asking for USB Permissions. After I approved that, my USB device started to show up in Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with connecting my Galaxy Nexus to win7 x64. I solved it by getting drivers, they can be downloaded from [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW) or also via Android SDK manager.

Comment: I downloaded the Google USB drivers from:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top
- connected the phone
- restarted the ADB deamon with "adb.exe usb"
- accepted the dialog window on my smartphone that asking me to accept the communication

Answer (score 4):

After you put your phone on developer mode, restart it. That worked for me, maybe it will work for you also. After restarting it, the phone was recognized, drivers were automatically installed. Note - I'm running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

I've been having this issue on Mac OSX Mavericks using Android Studio, using my Samsung Galaxy Express , I did a little trick, Run -> Edit Configurations - > Run -> Show chooser dialog. When I "play" and the dialog appeared, I connected my device and it did appear. ;)

Comment: even though i get 'usb device not found' error, Felipe's solution  works for me too, sometimes:
.. run
.. debug 'app'
(thank you Felipe)

Comment: i tried to edit, add to previous comment, but stackoverflow would not allow editing after 5 mintue window = new comment... if run/debug'app' does not work, opening activity monitor and quiting 'adb' also works some of the time.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a USB Type-C cable, check if it has the charging and **data transfer** capability. Many USB Type-C cables are for charging only, and are not recognized by Android Studio.

Comment: i bought a cable few days ago, it have both of the capabilities but it will disconnect after some time, so i have to change options everytime when it disconnects(from Charging to File-Transfer)..and again for some time it will work and then disconnect after few minutes(now change in reverse, from File-Transfer to Charging)..

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the driver first. Follow the instructions on the Android's developers website:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a Samsung galaxy note 2. It was recognized on one pc but not on another one (both running windows 7 64b). After hours of struggling, I installed Kies (from the Samsung website) on the pc where Android Studio was unable to detect the smartphone (Kies was installed on the other one).

Like magic, Android Studio detected the phone !!! I noticed that the Kies installer installed some driver for the phone.

Consequently, for those meeting the same detection problem, I would strongly advise to first install Kies.

Answer (score 2):

Galaxy S7, I had to go to Settings, Developer Options and allow USB Debugging. This asked to approve computer it was attached to and it showed up instantly.

Answer (score 2):

I had tried restart the device, and it's work, popup and ask want to trust the mac for debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Samung S8, I tried to install:

1. Intel Android Driver
2. Samsung USB driver

But the adb bridge driver was still missing.
I finally got it to work by installing the Samsung Smart Switch application which is a media manager application.

Updated at 2018-04-20: If you are struggle with the driver, just use http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

Check installed drivers. If drivers ok, check device usb-port it could be damaged.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4. Although visible from Devices, my phone was not listed as connected from Android Studio. I tried a few things independently, and then together, and found that only a **combination** of steps fixed the issue, so this is for you if measures listed above or on another site did not work on their own.

1. Enable USB debugging from "Developer Options"
2. Download Kies from Samsung. I believe Samsung US has replaced Kies with a new software called Smart Switch, but this did not resolve anything for me. I found a [Samsung UK download of Kies](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) that worked fine.
3. After connecting your phone to your PC via USB, go to your phone notifications and click on USB settings at the top. Switch it to Camera mode.

I repeat, only all 3 of these together fixed the issue, so if some fixes you have tried haven't worked, use these 3 and it could fix the problem for you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Restart Android Studio Worked in my case

Answer (score 1):

For me, this simple trick worked:

I actually enabled and disabled the listed USB Adapter for android in the device manager (Control Panel -> Hardware & Sound -> Device Manager). And holy moly it's working! :D

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was following the instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver. Specifically, the key part from that link that helped me to find the solution was this: "Install a USB Driver. First, find the appropriate driver for your device from the OEM drivers table below." This means that you cannot find a single link that applies to everyone as the solution. It will depend on your device! "So I visited the page to get OEM Drivers at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Drivers. In my case, the device I was using was an LG K8 LTE. I had to go to http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers#, Browse by product and I found the driver I needed under the Model Number "LGAS375 KG K8 ACG - AS375", Cell Phone Product. From http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-LGAS375 I used the "Install the USB DRIVER" for Windows (http://tool.lime.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=UW00120120425).

Depending on the device model you are using, you will need to find the specific drivers that work for your phone, and that should work.

Answer (score 1):

How to get connection to device working using **adb command line**:

USB debugging enabled on phone and phone connected.

I am exercising these commands on linux(redhat and ubuntu) but same commands work under the hood on windows. The device manager runs adb commands. You can find a console in your device manager or regular command-line works if you set up your paths to SDK.

If you can run adb and see something like ???????? in devices list ..

```
$ android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

You might be running the adb server as a regular user.
You might have to run the adb server as root. 
So kill the server as regular user and start it as root.

```
$ adb kill-server
$ which adb
$ sudo <fullpath>/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

Now look at adb devices list, if it is first time this machine connects to this phone you will see "unauthorized".

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
MWS0216A31xxxxxx    unauthorized
```

At this point on phone you should have dialog popped up and you can tap ok to authorize. Then you should see "device" in the devices list and commands like shell/push/pull/sync/backup... should work.

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
MWS0216A31xxxxxx    device

$ adb shell "uname -a; df; ls /storage/sdcard0/Download"
Linux localhost 3.10.90-g2ff1b22 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 27 17:12:50 CST 2016 aarch64
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                     1.3G   108.0K     1.3G   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup           1.3G    12.0K     1.3G   4096
/mnt                     1.3G     0.0K     1.3G   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids: Permission denied
/system                  2.4G     2.3G   106.8M   4096
/cust                  492.0M   327.7M   164.3M   4096
/cache                 248.0M   160.0K   247.8M   4096
/splash2: Permission denied
/3rdmodem               59.0M     4.9M    54.1M   1024
/3rdmodemnvm: Permission denied
. .
/storage                 1.3G     0.0K     1.3G   4096
/data                   25.1G    10.9G    14.2G   4096
/mnt/runtime/default/emulated: Permission denied
/storage/emulated       25.1G    11.2G    13.8G   4096
/mnt/runtime/read/emulated: Permission denied
/mnt/runtime/write/emulated: Permission denied
.
.
```

Lovely jubly. Hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

My file path:

```
C:\...\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf
```

My data to paste:

```
;Tablet PC

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0003&MI_01

%CompositeADBInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0003&REV_0230&MI_01
```

Comment: This looks like it should be a comment on [Guilherme's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22887262/507761).

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case updating drivers, restarting Android Studio, restarting my phone, changing the USB mode or unplugging USB did not help.

Then I went to the dev settings in my phone, toggled the Dev. Mode off and back on, and it worked. AS was open and phone was plugged at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem occurring suddenly in Dell Ubuntu linux machine with Android Developer Studio. I did the following steps

```
    1. I opened "System Settings"
    2. Select the listed item "Software and Updates"
    3. Click on the tab "Additional Drivers"
    4. There was a mention about "Dell Inc: Unknown" and the option "Do not use use the device" selected. I selected the alternate driver mentioned and did an "Apply the Changes".
```

It started working.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran adb command prompt and hit 'adb devices' and it showed daemon was not running. It installed itself and now i can able to see android devices there.

```
C:\...\...\source\repos\ABC\ABC\Ex.Android>adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
ZF22Q3T      unauthorized
```

and Reload the project

Answer (score 0):

Windows, many times it will not recognize the device fully and because of driver issues, the device won't show up.

- 1).go to settings

  2).control panel

  3).hardware and sound

  4).device manager

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restarted my PC and worked in my case.