# Emulating Apps on Android Studio using Hardware Device

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Hi guys My hardware device is not being detected by the Android Studio yet i have enabled usb debugging. I have also tried troubleshooting and still i have not found out where the problem is..Please help

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions have been asked already so many times. Meanwhile, you did not provide enough information on your particular case. Anyways, check these Q&As, maybe they'll help you solve the issue:

[Android studio doesn't list my phone under "Choose Device"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225927/android-studio-doesnt-list-my-phone-under-choose-device)

[Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)