# Android Studio Physical device connection problem

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

At the beginning my pc android studio did not connect my mobile device. Then Then this solution work for me.
[Solution Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25226019/10833212)

but now new problem arrive.When I connected my mobile device with my pc, USB is connected fine, I can share file but connection between android studio and my device lost and connect automatically.For that I can't debug properly.

my mobile model number:  HUAWEI TIT-AL00

Android Studio Version: 3.5.2

Thank you advance

Comment: Are you sure that the cable that you are using is in good condition? sometimes it may be defective. And make sure you enabled developer options in your phone

Comment: developer mode on with USB debugging on?

Comment: mobile developer option and USB cable are okay because I worked with them another PC.

Comment: Install the driver for your huaweii device in your pc. Google search and you can easily find your device model specific driver