# USB device not found

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, motorola

When I try to run or debug my app this appears in "debug" of Android Studio:

> Waiting for device.
>   USB device not found

My phone is a: Motorola RAZR D1 TV. It connects to the PC (even if in debug mode).
I'm working on Windows 8.1 64 bits (running in no certificate detection for USB mode).
I have Java 1.8.0_25.
I tried to set the 'android_winusb.inf' file as said in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22887262/3124150. I have to say that none of my USB connectors appear abnormal.

Comment: Try to reinstall the driver with `adbdriver` freeware

Comment: @Blaze Tama This one: http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ (first option)?

Comment: Worked after restart!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had been having this issue with a device of mine as well.

First, check that the device is in debug mode. If it isn't, try everything again.

If it *still* isn't showing up, even when in debug mode, then your issue is probably a lack of drivers.

Open up your SDK Manager (it'll be a button at the top of your IDE, or you can find it in the Android SDK download folder), scroll down to the bottom, and download the USB drivers. This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: My phone is in debug mode and Google USB Driver (rev. 11) is installed.

Comment: You may want to try some outside sources for the drivers. I do think that the problem for you is driver-related.

Answer (score -1):

Wow Ok I have wasted more or less 3 hours dealing with this same issue after much thinkering what worked for me is downloading  this [Unified Android Toolkit](http://www.skipsoft.net/?wpdmpro=unified-android-toolkit-v1-4-0)

And using it to download the correct driver for my Samsung phone but there are also drivers for other brands.