# Android Galaxy Young GT-S6312 is not displaying in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile

I am trying to connect my mobile device for debugging in Android Studio but it shows "`No device connected`" even though my device is connected to the computer. I have tried to update drivers for "`unknown device`" and Samsung_Android in the Device Manager but it failed.

I have already installed Google USB driver and tried to update my device driver through it also, but it shows an error.

I have also tried to follow instruction from this page [Android device is not connected to USB for debugging (Android studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509422/android-device-is-not-connected-to-usb-for-debugging-android-studio/19461399#19461399), but I am unable to solve my problem.

I am also unable to find a driver for my device (Samsung Galaxy Young GT-S6312).

How can I get Android Studio to recognize my Android Galaxy Young GT-S6312?

Comment: Welcome! I have edited your question. You say that Google USB driver showed an error, could you tell us which one? Are there other devices that your installation of Android Studio does recognize? And, which version of Android Studio are you using? You can edit these things into your post; it might help us to diagnose the problem. Good luck!

Comment: @ Downvoter / close voter: this question seems OK to me. The user is not asking "where is a driver", but explains the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall driver you installed then download and install this driver : 
[samsung galaxy young gt -s6312 driver](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-S6310ZWNBTU)

then restart adb

Comment: your welcome @abhishekraj chose the best answer if its useful and your problem solved.

Comment: Wow!! It worked. I re-installed my Samsung driver and it worked. Again thanks for the link @meysam. Now my device is showing in android studio. Woooo...

Answer (score 0):

Delete the driver you have 
And install this http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117#none