# Mi A2 phone is not detected in android studio via usb

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a redmi Mi A2 phone and want to use for debugging apps created by android studio, but the phone is not detected via usb. How do I get my phone to detect in android studio?

I've tried rebooting and also enabled USB debugging in developer options but it still does work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test android apps in a real device with Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947834/how-to-test-android-apps-in-a-real-device-with-android-studio)

Comment: Also [Android device is not connected to USB for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509422/android-device-is-not-connected-to-usb-for-debugging-android-studio)

Comment: You might be missing a [USB driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb).

Answer (score 0):

Please check in Developer Options > turn on USB debugging > also check Install via USB turn on

Answer (score 0):

Please check your developer options is on or not and turn on USB debugging also click on transfer file from the notification tray.

Comment: The problem is USB preference is disabled, so can't select file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you dont have access to USB preference to active the transfer file from notification tray, go to 'Developer Options' > (in Networking section)'Select USB Configuration' > and select the 'file transfer' or 'MTP (Media transfer protocol' depending which android versio you have.
After turn on USB debugging at Developer Options > turn on USB debugging.

Comment: Have tried it but no data transfer is selected by default and the whole settings is disable.