# Android on Linux - Cannot test my app on my android device

Tags: android, linux

I am following the official tutorial on android developing from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html). So when I connected my Moto G phone with a USB cable to my Xubuntu 14.04 system and enabled developer mode, Android Studio recognized the device, however it said `[UNAUTHORIZED]` next to it. It still allowed me to run, and the result was just a `Waiting for device` message that never went away. My phone didn't respond. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device ?

Comment: If you disconnect and connect your device again, you should get a dialog on the device asking if you want to authorize debug access from your PC. Answer appropriately.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks. That happened once I changed the setting as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The problem was in my phone's security settings. I had to uncheck the `Verify apps over USB` option and it worked out just fine.