# Android Studio doesn't show my sony xperia tipo

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-virtual-device

Android studio doesn't show my device to debug apps. Everything is installed and working properly except android studio. Adb driver is installed and i tried apkinstaller software, it show my device.

My device api level is 15 and api installed in android studio is 21. Any one have idea may be due to change of api level android studio is not showing my device or something else.
i already tried these posts which was posted on stackover

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Am i missing something?

Comment: Did you install the Google USB drivers? Also, you can download an older API level with the SDK manager in Android Studio.

Comment: Google usb drivers already installed. yes now i have to download 15 api level. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be caused by **many reasons**, some of them:

1. Check if [`Google USB drivers`](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) is installed
2. Check if `developers options` is enabled
3. Check if `USB debugging` is enabled
4. Check `USB Connection` in `Device Settings` *(play with Media
   Device[MTP] and Camera[PTP])*
5. Plug `off/on` usb cable
6. Restart adb: kill
   [*from console:* `kill-all adb`
   *from windows:* kill it from `TaskManager`] and start it again
7. Download `Samsung Kies Software` from [here](http://www.samsung.com/tr/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) (it will download some
   `drivers` too, while installing this software `plug off` your device and
   after it finishes `plug in` and try it)
8. Some more
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Comment: drivers installed, developers option and usb debugging enabled. In my device there is only MTP and MSC so i enable msc.

Comment: @ScorpionPk so? Still any problem? Try `MTP` also and plug off/on your cable

Comment: Yes, still there is problem. someone suggest me to download again android studio and sdk so now waiting for download complete.

I accept your answer and please rate my question.

Comment: Another possible reason (for you Googlers): you don't have enough power in your USB port. I had a device plugged in to a USB port on my Dell monitor (u2415) and even though the device was charging, it didn't get detected by Windows or Android Studio. It showed up immediately when I plugged it in directly to my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

7 clicks over "compiller number" in "about the phone" in your smartphone, it enable developer options, after that enable usb debugging option and allow that Android Studio detect the phone

Answer (score 1):

Download and Install [Moborobo](http://download.moborobo.com/download/Client/MoboMarketPC_v5.0.1.68(official).exe) for all android Smart phone USB drivers.Then open moborobo and plug the android device.If your device driver not there it will get install automatically by Moborobo.Then restart your IDE to detect the device.

@hrskrs also value answer only ,but some times lower level devices would give this kind of issues.

Comment: Boopathi i already installed device driver from official site of Sony xperia. Do i really need to install this driver?

Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Xperia L1, It works with the [ADB Driver Installer](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/):

- Unzip and execute ADBDriverInstaller.
- Connect your phone with USB depuration enabled, click "Refresh" in ADB Driver Installer.
- If your phone is not in list, the default driver (or another) is installed, click on "Device Manager" search your phone, right click, uninstall current driver. disconnect and connect your phone and click "Refresh" in in ADB Driver Installer.
- Select your phone in list and click "Install".