# Device Not getting displayed on AVD manager in windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am using a windows 7 with two user account and am not using the administrator account.My phone Motorola when connected via USB (USB Debugging Enabled) Its not getting showed in the avd manager screen. The phone is getting detected as Storage device in my computer. I installed the google usb driver and the scenario remains the same. Can Anyone help me for configuring this correctly. Thank You

Comment: did you try installing the custom ADB driver from the vendor?

Comment: Nope can you tell how to do that @Arslan

Comment: try to find adb driver with your motorola device model on google. and see if you can find. and if it helps i can post it as answer. :P

Comment: you need admin rights and usb rights in order to view your connected devices.

Comment: That means I must be logged in from the administrator account isnt it ? @SMR

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging on the device?

Comment: yes you need to login using an admin account

Comment: @Arslan Your answer solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try with pda.net driver, which cover most of android devices, link http://pdanet.co/a/

Please check your App target sdk version and Device OS.
Also you can refer [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)