# mobile devices are not getting connected with android studio

Tags: android

I am new on Android Development. I have installed Android Studio and it is not picking any android device (Nexus 5, Sony Xperia Z, Samsung Note II). I am on window 7-64bit.

Comment: is USBDebugging enabled?

Comment: @Mohit I have enabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't see device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Comment: try kill and re start adb server

Answer (score 0):

- Activate developer mode
- Activate debug mode
- Download drivers for the device

Profit.

Comment: Android studio don't need any device drivers, and even I have nexus 5, It is google device.

Comment: A driver has nothing to do with android studio or even if you're using a google device...... If you're running android studio on windows you will need the google usb driver to enable debugging. You sayed you are new , and then you know what's needed ? Stupid.

Answer (score 0):

At first be sure that you install Google USB Driver in the SDK.

Then go to control panel -> devices -> your device, then click check for updates -> browse from desktop -> target to this folder \extras\google\usb_driver

Answer (score -1):

You have do enable developer mode on your device and also debug usb.

Comment: I have done this these two steps, but still same problem.