# My Device Does't show in android studio when i try to run app on my physical device on windows 7

Tags: android

Two days have been passed but still i am unable to run apps on my physical mobile device. I have "ASUS Zenfone 5"(made in china). I am unable to install driver . I have downloaded the driver but when i try to install a problem occurred kindly anyone let me know how i can run apps on my device.i will be thankful to you.

Comment: Download latest adb drivers for your system and try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't see device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.coderefer.com/test-android-app-real-device/

try to follow steps mentioned in link