# Connect Phone to Machine (ADB)

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, ubuntu-14.04

I have a android app I want to put to my phone. I cant get my device connected even, MOTO G Android 6.

```
[Ubuntu 14.04][Android 6 Phone]
```

I have usb debugging allowed and MTP enabled.

I have my udev rules of motorola id 22b8. I added the id to adb_usb.uni file.

Still no sign of any connection. sudo adb devies returns a blank line. adb starting restarting killing nothing changes anything.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device/16598454

Comment: @Nirojthapa thanks, but i just want to install an apk using adb command line. I

Comment: adb install example.apk installs your apk in internal memroy of emulator where as adb install -s example.apk installs the apk in sd card from adb command shell