# Android studio linux doesn't see authorized device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Studio doesn't show my Asus Zenfone 5 in the window of selecting target. 
`adb devices` shows it. Tried changing MTP PTP, restarting `adb`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this one help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: daylight, no it doesn't

Comment: Shobhit Puri, Android studio 2.2

Comment: In Studio. Tools > Android > ADB Integration. Try to toggle that

Answer (score -1):

Revoke USB debugging authorization from settings -> developer options

Comment: Nope, unfortunately didn't help