# El Capitan does not detect Meizu4

Tags: macos

currently i'm trying to connect my `Meizu4` device to `El Capitan 10.11.6`.

I tried using sync-mate and nothing happen.

I already allow debugging mode and Media-Transfer-Protocol (MTP), still nothing happen

Would anyone be able to help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to download "android file transfer" on your mac. https://www.android.com/filetransfer/ and then connect with your USB cable

Comment: Thanks, but still my Mac unable to detect android device

Comment: use the PTP when usb debugging instead of media-transfer-protocol (MTP)

Comment: If android file transfer software didn't work you can try the AirDroid app. Once installed on phone you go to airdroid.com and sign in. Description: AirDroid allows you to access and manage your Android phone or tablet from Windows, Mac or the Web, wirelessly, for free. Transfer files between your devices, and share files to your friends.

Comment: With mode PTP nothing happen, but with AirDroid app  my phone able to connect perfectly.

Comment: Would like to ask something @NoobasaurusRex, 

currently i'm developing and apps, so `Android Studio` still does not detect my Mx4 after installing `AirDroid app`.

Comment: @user3648961 Glad to hear AirDroid worked for you. To your question about Android Studio, this has been already been answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device/16598454. Best of luck to you.