# android studio doesn't see USB connected device

Tags: android, android-studio, connection, usb, device

Just to be clear, the device isn't locked or anything and it works perfectly  for my friend who has the same android studio version. The problem isn't with detecting the usb device (by the computer), I can access the device's content just perfectly so it connects correctly to my computer but not to android studio.
When I try to run an application, the usb device doesn't show amongst the options.
Can someone please help me with this issue, knowing that my android studio is updated.

UPDATE:
the devices I used are: Samsung J2 and J3

Comment: Check adb devices? Do you see your device in this list?

Comment: which device you are using ?

Comment: try restarting the adb server first, if not working then restart the mobile device and reconnect it

Comment: no I can't see my device in the sdb devices list and that is the problem. I thought the problem was with my usb port but my computer does recognise my device (I can access data on my phone through my computer properly)

Comment: I tried restarting the adb server musltiple times too but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed Universal USB Driver, if no then you will not see any device to connect. you can also install individual company device driver.

just try Universal USB Driver to connect all devices

Download from here [Universal USB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Open the `Device Manager` window from the `control panel` in your computer. In the Others/Unknown Devices tab you would see an unknown android device. Right click on it and update the driver and re-run android studio.

Comment: As I have said, my computer recognises the device perfectly. The problem is that android studio doesn't.

Comment: Sometimes your driver is outdated so the device would be detected perfectly but it won't work with android studio until you update it. I had the same issue and solved it as i mentioned above.

Comment: I tried doing that but I got the message "all drivers are updated"

Comment: have you tried the solution given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure usb debugging is on in your device.
In Android Studio
Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration

**Enable ADB Integration**
Then run app

Hope it will solve the problem

Comment: thank you for your reply but I found it was already checked (default settings)

Answer (score 0):

Enable your ADB in your Android

-> First go to Settings->Developer Options

-> Then On or Enable your ADB Mode

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I use Samsung too.

I fixed it by installing the device driver from Samsung which you can download from [Samsung's website](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/app/smart-switch)

Note

1. You need to enable ADB mode(Like the second comment)
2. You need to set Target in Android Studio to > Open Select Deployment Target Dialog
3. to set Target : Run > Edit
   Configurations > Targets > Open Select Deployment Target Dialog

Answer (score -1):

Just a `Restart` of `Android Studio` worked for me.

In my case it happened because of non-interaction in `Android_Studio` for long.

Else, Check with `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Target`.