# Why android studio cant detect my phone for debugging?

Tags: android

Ive get started learning android development and I have this problem that when I connect my phone(samsung s4) for debugging its wont appear on the 'Select Deployment Target' dialog box. I hope you can help me fix this problem.

Question is:

**How to debug with external device?**

Comment: Have you turned on the `USB debugging` in `Developer options` on the device ?

Comment: Did you enable usb debugging on your phone ? (settings > developer options > enable usb debugging)

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device) for multiple answers

Comment: yes that's the first thing I'd done, I also try to put my phone on PTP mode. @ Robert Banyai

Comment: have you installed the respective drivers ?

Comment: Ive tried updating the driver, but it wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible solutions
first you should enable usb debugging

### Solution 1

go to

> About device=>tap 7 times on build number=>you are now a developer

go to

> settings => developer options => enable usb debugging

### Solution 2

[download](https://androidmtk.com/download-samsung-usb-drivers) samsung driver for samsung galaxy phones

and try again

Comment: @renannuevo did you installed this driver?

Comment: I've also installed the API(5.0.1, lollipop) which corresponds to that of my phone. I thought it will work.

Comment: No No install that driver what I specified.

Comment: OK sir.. I will this. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Let me know the result

Comment: for your phone samsung galaxy s4

Comment: go to [this](http://samsungusbdriver.com/wp-content/uploads/Samsung-Usb-Driver-v1.5.63.0.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to activate USB debugging?

To activate it, open settings -> about device(can be about phone or about tablet) -> tap "Build number" a few times until a toast comes up that says "You are now a developer".

You will get toasts saying "You are now X steps away from being a developer".

WHen it reaches 0, you will not see that message, you will see "You are now a developer" and can access the developer settings.

From there, go into the developer settings, find and activate USB debugging.

**-- ALSO SEE --**

[this](https://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/)

[this(youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ucs34BkfPB0)

**UPDATE**

If you have activated USB debugging AND it still doesn't show up, see if the drivers are installed. When I got my S6 and tried to connect it, it wouldn't show up anywhere. For me, the solution was to open WIndows Update and download the driver that now showed up there.

Also see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68AATUTMogE)