# Android Studio does not detect Android device on Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, usb, device

I am setting up a Android development environment on a new Windows 10 laptop. I have done this many times on other machines with other operating systems, but this is the first time with Windows 10. The problem is that Android Studio cannot detect my device (LG Zone 3) after I connect it via USB. Note that I have previously used this device for development on an Arch Linux desktop.

I have downloaded Android Studio and created several AVDs. I can run my app and tests on those just fine. However, my hardware device is not listed in the selection dialog.

Here are some things I have tried:

- Check that the USB drivers are installed.
- Restart ADB from the Android Monitor window in Android Studio
- Restart ADB from the command line with `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`.
- Quit Android Studio and restart it.
- Unplug the device, turn off USB debugging, and turn it back on.
- Plug device into a different USB port.
- Switch device connection settings to Charge Only and then back to MTP.

What other trouble-shooting steps can I follow to get my device to work?

Comment: Switching to another USB port did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending of your device you might be required to install the phone specific drivers.
Also, sometimes it helps if you go to phone Developer settings and uncheck/disable  USB debugging and enable it again.

Comment: > Unplug the device, turn off USB debugging, and turn it back on

Comment: Where do I get the device-specific drivers?

Comment: What device you have  ? Ussualy from producer site

Comment: I found [this download page](https://www.mylgphones.com/lg-android-usb-device-drivers). How do I know if it is legit?

Comment: For my LG I downloaded driver from http://tool.lime.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=UW00120120425

Comment: p.s. I have an LG Zone 3. I edited my question to include that detail as well.

Comment: I have found that link using http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers

Comment: After installing a driver from the link I gave above, my device prompted me to "allow usb debugging", so I think it worked. I rebooted my laptop just as that dialog apppeared so I am now in the process of restarting AS to check it out.

Comment: Installing LG-specific drivers solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are few ways to resolve this problem.

Case 1. Enable the USB debugging option in your mobile.

**Setting > developer > Check "USB Debugging"**

Case 2. Change from **MTP to PTP**.(sometimes vise versa works)

Case 3. If nothing worked then try **to Install PdaNet+ in your system.** This Actually worked for me.

If it solved your issue then answer this question in the comment section > **Which case solved your issue?** it will help the coming people who are facing the similar problem.

Comment: changing from MTP to PTP helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25974310

Comment: Upon connecting the cable, I was prompted to allow access.  Because I never chose the "Always" option, it defaulted to "Charging" or "File transfer".  Enabling ""USB debugging" in "Developer options" and then going back to "USB options" (via notification tray at top) and changing it to "Photo transfer".... allowed my device (G6, Oreo/8.0) to be visible to Win 10 (via `flutter devices`)

Answer (score 3):

Try this also

1.Just change your cable & give try again

2.Uncheck "Tools" - "Android" - "Enable ADB Integration".

3.Re-Install Google USB drivers

GOTO - http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top
Download the driver
Reinstall it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. After downloading and installing drivers specific to my device, AS can now find it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, an LG device, I just downloaded drivers from the lg site, and it fixed the problem without having to fiddle with any settings.
LG site: http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I discovered that my device was paired via Bluetooth to my Windows 10 machine. This was preventing it from being listed as a portable device keeping it hidden from Android Studio so make sure the two are not paired.