# How to use SQLite emulator database on Android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

Note: The answer to this question establishes the solution for using SQLite. I have written another question for seeing devices.

I am having a bit of trouble trying to find the solution to this. I think the main issue is that I cannot see my emulator in the 'Devices' tab in the Android Device Monitor - as you can see below.
[image]

Most of the issues address going into this Device manager and the file explorer even with the emulator, but I assume that's an older eclipse solution.

Does someone know how to make the emulator visible in the device manager?

Answer (score 1):

Steps :

1) Download the jar SQLite browser plugin from https://github.com/TKlerx/android-sqlite-browser-for-eclipse/releases

2) Put the jar in: [YourAndroidSdkDirectory]/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/plugins/AndroidSQLiteBrowser_1.0.1.jar

3) Restart the Android Device Monitor.

4) Select the .db file inside the device(rooted) or the emulator and click on the SQLite browser on the top right corner next to the (+) new folder button.

Enjoy...

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. Steps 1-3 are fine ( I think). Just having trouble locating what you mean. Do you mean after 'running' the app I'm meant to see something on the top right of the emulator? Or is this meant to be in one of the device managers?

Comment: once your jar file setup successfully you can see this 
https://i1.wp.com/www.instinctcoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/AS_BrowseData_04.jpg
 SQLite browswer button  , and if you cant see this button that means you have done something wrong..

Comment: Am I also meant to see my emulator in the devices though? Like in my picture, there are no devices on display in the actual device monitor.

Comment: Oh , restart your adb and try again i think it will works for you

Comment: please check this link i think it can be help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device

Comment: I clicked "reset adb" in the drop down menu (above name in the pic above) and I got this in the DDMS log:
[2017-06-10 17:16:50 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2017-06-10 17:16:51 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146311/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-michael-potts).