# I don't see my device in Android Studio devices

Tags: android-studio, usb

I read a lot for my problem, but still didn't find solution. I have Huawei P9 Lite. I install Google Usb Driver, but I don't see my device. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried, why do you think this is happening?

Comment: In Settings/Android SDK/SDK Tools I found and installed Google USB Driver. I connected my phone with USB cable and click on File Manager(MTP) connection. I tried also with Camera(PTP) connection. Still no results. I have Programmer Options switched on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect your phone to your PC and press RUN app in AS, a window will pop-up and it will say no devices connected. Go to settings in your phone, enable developer options, and enable usb-debugging, and then your phone will be displayed in that window.

Comment: Enable developer options by going to settings on your phone,about phone and keep tapping build number until it says "now you're a developer"