# Android device not recognizing

Tags: android, usb, adb, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying run android apk in Huawei tablet. In Android studio shows the connected device as none. In Hisuite also displays as Device not connected. But the device appears in device manager and I can access the data inside device through PC. adb not recognize.

[image: Scrreenshot1]

[image: Scrreenshot2]

Device - HUAWEI Mediapad T3 10(Android 7.0)

PC OS- Windows 7

Android Studio 2.3.3

HiSuite 5.0.1.300_OVE

Comment: install Google usb driver from your Android sdk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device

Comment: Check the above Link. Different methods are explained there

Comment: Try this Driver http://phoneusbdrivers.com/huawei-mediapad-usb-driver/

Comment: Restore default setting in developer option then reconnect the device solved the issue. thankx all

Answer (score 5):

Enable [**Developer Options**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html). In Developer Options enable **USB Debugging**.

Make Sure that **Google USB Driver** and [**ADB**](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html) is installed

Change USB Mode to **MTP**

After Connecting to Allow Computer **Enable USB Debugging on this Computer dialog** will appear. Allow it .

After that Notification Window will show  **USB Debbuging is Enabled**  whenever you connect via USB on to the System. If it is not Shown Download the Phones Driver for the System. Because the System may Be Lacking the Corresponding device Driver.

If Debbuging Privellage is Revoked Then Go to Developer Options. Use Revoke all USB Permssions on Computer.

Also refer [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Comment: thankx for the response Tomin. I have already enabled the USB Debugging.  Problem should be with the computer since tablet working properly in my colleague's machine