# Android studio doesn't recognize my phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the google usb driver installed and updated, no other driver missing in the sdk, same in the computer but my phonedoesn't appear in the list when I try to run my code.
The usb debugging is activated.

Comment: When you plug your phone into your computer, does your phone say it is USB Debugging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Answer (score 5):

Turn on `USB debugging` toggle in Developers options of your android device:

1. Go to [About phone] in the Settings Menu of your device, find the item called [Build number], Click on it Several times, until a Toast prompt you with "You are now a developer" message.
2. Go into [Developer options], Find [USB debugging] and Toggle it on.

Now, in most cases, that's All you need to do.

But in some cases, Windows Or MAC cannot even recognize the phone is plugged-in.

In such case, You need Download Your Phones USB Driver.

Install it, And you should be good to go.

---> FOR TESTING IF YOUR DEVICE IS SYNCED WITH THE PC OR NOT:

1. Open a Command prompt, from [Platform-tools] Directory where Android is installed.
2. Then type in `adb devices` and hit Enter

It'll give you the Device ID, which means your phone is connected.

If The Message was saying "No Device Found", Means that your phone is connected but USB debugging is OFF, or Your phone still isn't connected properly.

Now, IF You have all of this ready, and you Still Cannot find your Device connected in Android Studio. Try THis:

---> When you plug your phone, There are several ways you can interact with the device Right?

One is Charging [Charge this device] - One is [Transfer files] - One is [Use device as MIDI] - etc

Toggle the phone On for [Charge this device] and See if Android Studio recognizes your phone or not.

if not, the problem is either Bad Cable or Bad USB ports.

Hope this answer is useful

Answer (score 2):

"Toggle the phone On for [Charge this device] and See if Android Studio recognizes your phone or not."

Totally works, i made an account just to say it xdd

Answer (score 0):

If in your device USB debugging is enabled already, try this:

1. Connect to your wi-fi network.
2. Find your IP
3. Enter to Android Studio's terminal the command:

> adb connect 192.168.0.x

(where x - individual for your device, that your device got from DHCP)

4. Confirm that you agree with USB debugging on this device and check the box that you always allow this computer to use USB debugging.
5. Repeat (3) adb connect 192.168.0.x

Profit.

I always connect my TV devices using this way without installing any drivers.