# I am not able to do usb debugging on my mac in android studio with samsung galaxy a8 and redmi n4

Tags: java, android

I tried to do USB debugging on my mac samsung galaxy a8 and redmi n4
what should I do?

I have the USB debugging enabled on both the phones but the Android Studio is not detecting them

please help me!!

Comment: possible of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device

Comment: 1) upgrade/install google usb drivers in SDK
2) change port
3) change cable
4) set path for SDK/Tools
5) Change connection type
6) Try stackoverflow search feature

Comment: Specify the android studio version next time you post please it really helps in understanding a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

It could be your USB cable as there are two types of USB cables ones that supply power only and ones that supply power and data passthrough. I would recommend trying a different USB cable. hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is finicky with Samsung phones being used as testing devices I had a lot of trouble connecting my s7 to my Mac. You should consider using a emulator on your Mac. Also check the cable some cables are not meant to be used as data transferring cables and simply cannot handle powering and transferring data. Try to use a wire made by a reputable source if you already have not. Finally update android studio and reboot your Mac. Refer to the website below to double check your steps.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different cable but this may not solve your problem sometimes android studio does not recognize certain phones that are not too popular I have a Axon 7 it doesn’t work sometimes. Finally try updating android studio because on the website it says once you plug in a device it should “just work”.