# Emulators not presented in Android Studio run dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0, android-virtual-device

I am facing an issue with my Android Studio 3.1.2. running on my OS X 10.13.4.
Despite the fact that I have installed 2 simulators, as you can see in my second screenshot, I can't run to any of them! None of my emulators are presented in my Select Deployment Target dialog.

I have already deleted the whole Android Studio and reinstall it without any luck.

Any thoughts?

[image: None of emulators are presented in Select Deployment Target dialog]

[image: Devices are presented here]

Comment: funny Android Studio bugs (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device/16598454#16598454)