# Android Studio does not recognize my LG5 device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using `Windows 10` with `Android Studio`'s latest version.

I have configured my LG device to be in `developer mode` (clicked 7 times on the build number and got message that I am in `developer mode`).
When I try to debug my app on the LG device, I get popup that tells me that there is "No connected device".

What could be the reason for that?

I can see the device on `My Computer` as a media device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Comment: No, this is relevant to g5 and windows 10

Comment: have you installed the drivers for your LG phone

Comment: How I do it on windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to being a `developer`, you must also enable debugging. Try going into `Developer Options` and turning on `USB Debugging`.

Answer (score 0):

You just enabled Developer Options. You need to enable USB Debugging.

Go to Your phone's Settings then go to Developer options and enable USB debugging there.

Also sometimes if you connect a new device to your pc it will install some built-in drivers for the device. So make sure you allow that process to be finished.

Still if the problem persists try another port of your computer.

P.S. For first time connection your phone will ask you to allow debugging permission from pc.

Comment: I turned on debugging but still the same problem.

Comment: Are your phone's drivers installed on your computer?

Comment: When you connect your device to your PC using USB do you see a USB debugging notification on your phone?