# Where is "Enable ADB Integration" Option in Android studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi When I started the android studio 3.3 the ADB was not initializing but there is no 'android ' options under the tool menu so where will I get the adb integration option?

Answer (score 10):

Enable ADB Integration is removed from 3.+ versions. It gets active automatically. Still if you want to reset-set it, you can check Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment -> Debugger -> Use libusb backend(check/uncheck) it.