# ADB is not working in any project any device as well as any emulator in my Android Studio. showing blank nothing else

Tags: android

Project run perfectly by creating build. Whenever I am going to run the any project its first showing initializing ADB and after 1-2 sec it's totally blank without any output.[image]

Comment: add virtual device .... or you can connect your phone with it goto setting > debugger options > tun on usb debugging. After that change mobile setting to file sharing then try again

Comment: I always use virtual device but suddenly today i am facing this problem.

Comment: try to invalide cache and restart

Comment: that's tried too. tried:
invalidate cache and restart.
updated USB driver.
cleared studio cache memory.
but still unable to fix it till now.

Comment: its not even showing Virtual Devices tab......

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the device is connected properly and USB Debugging is enabled. You can enable debugging in developer options in your android device.
Second, open terminal and type the following commands:

1. `adb devices`: This should list the devices connected to the computer. If you see an error saying `adb command not found`, you'll have to add Android SDK to your path. You can find the instructions here: https://9to5google.com/2014/12/02/how-to-install-adb-tools-windows-mac-linux/
2. `adb kill-server`: This will kill the ADB Server
3. `adb start-server`: This will start the server.

After you have restarted the adb server, try the 1st command again and you should see your device. After you see the device, restart Android Studio and same will appear in the window.

Comment: I have tried this way too but unable to fix it. After cleared the cache from Android Studio & got this problem.

Comment: Solved!! First Update the Android Studio then change the adb.
<user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe