# android studio does not detect my phone although adb does

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have installed android studio 3.5.1 and universal ADB version 6 and my phone's(which is honor 8c with android 8) driver on windows 10. 
but the problem is that my android studio does not recognize my phone when I connect it to laptop via USB although ADB does recognize it. the USB debugging is enabled on phone and I have tried file transferring, photo transferring and charge only mode but it doesn't work.
and my CPU is AMD, not Intel, so I tried enabling windows hypervisor platform but it didn't solve the problem. any idea what am I doing wrong?

one of the answers is [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device) but the problem is that there is no project in my Edit Configurations window.

Answer (score 0):

I was having some related issues like yours after updating to Android Studio 3.5.1 and I found a solution, but I'm running on Mac, and I'm not entirely sure if this solution does work on Windows as well, but here it is:

Open Android Studio Preferences, then on search bar look for `adb` and click on `Debugger`, here we have an option called `Use libusb backend` that is unchecked by default, check it and click on `APPLY` and `OK`, now I can see my device

[[image: Preferences[1]]