# adb (windows 8.1) can't find my device (honor 8x)

Tags: android, adb

I want to debug a mobile application in my device. I installed `adb` but it wasn't recognizing my phone.

What I already did :

- I activated developer mode;
- I checked `USB debugging`;
- I checked `stay awake`;
- I checked `Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode`. (if that matters).

I know my cable can be used to debug as it has been previously used by a friend of mine to debug using his own devices.

After some research, I found that Windows 8.1 doesn't have an out-of-the-box driver for honor 8X, so I installed one following [this tutorial](https://huaweiflash.com/huawei-honor-8x-usb-driver/) and it was recognized in Windows' Device Manager.

Nevertheless, my phone wasn't recognized and I tried every "input method" possible:

1. Transfer photos;
2. Transfer files;
3. Charge only;
4. Input MDI.

Everytime I change this setting I do :

- `adb kill-server`
- `adb devices` (it automatically runs `adb start-server` under the hood)

But I get the same output everytime :

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
```

Where can the problem be ?

Comment: Please see the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Raluca but it's not the same problem. For me, even `adb` doesn't list my connected device. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it is most probably that the device drivers are not installed properly.

First, install Google USB Driver from Android SDK Manager.

Then, go to Start, right-click on My Computer, select Properties and go to Device Manager on the left. Locate you device under Other Devices (Unknown devices, USB Devices). Right-click on it and select Properties. Navigate to Driver tab. Select Update Driver and then Browse my computer for driver software. Choose %ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\extras\google\usb_driver directory. Windows should find and install drivers there. Then run adb kill-server. Next time you do adb devices the device should be in the list