# What to do if I can see my USB connected Samsung device in ADB terminal but can't see it in Android Studio in Mac OS?

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-galaxy

I have a Samsung S10e, and while I can run `adb devices` in `~Library/Android/sdk/tools` and see my device connected through my USB cable, when I open Android Studio, the only available devices in the drop down menu are virtual devices. After reinstalling and restarting multiple times, I'm at a loss for what to do.

Comment: Give this a try, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25974310/9617459

Comment: @codervishal There are no MTP or PTP options, but I did try changing the USB file transfer type between "Transferring files" and "Transferring images", along with revoking USB access and renabling access, and it still doesn't show up in AS.

Comment: Oh, there might be some files caching problem in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason reinstalling Android Studio one last time was what made it work. I used the top comment here as a guide: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)

I didn't uninstall everything, but I deleted the application as well as the virtual devices.