# Devices not available in Android Studio and Intelij Idea

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

I'm working on virtual machine ( OS Win10 ) using Intelij Idea and Android Studio. I have field Devices empty in both IDEs when developing Android apps.

Screen shots :

[Intelij Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgrwy.png)

[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEuvQ.png)

Flutter Doctor says:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-2.0.pre.114, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388], locale pl-PL)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Program
    X Android Studio not found at C:\Program
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

I have 3 connected devices.

```
3 connected devices:

Web Server (web) • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
Chrome (web)     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 84.0.4147.89
Edge (web)       • edge       • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 84.0.522.40
```

Why I cant see them in IDEs ?
Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you checked this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device

Comment: Thats not a problem. I cant put my device via USB because my virtual machine which I use for developing is in cloud. I need to find Chrome / edge / whatever on devices list but it isnt there.