# Phone Not Detected as Android Device on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My phone ( Pixel 3xl) is detected by the connection assistant on Android Studio. However, if I try to press run, Android Studio states that no connected devices are found. I have already enabled developers option on my phone. I have also tried changing the USB connection from PTP, MIDI, USB tethering and File transfer. However, none of them seem to work. What could be the issue here?

[image]

Edit: I have also ran `adb devices` and it displays my phone. However, I still cant run it on Android Studio

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see the device in Logcat section? And are you running a flutter project?

Comment: How do i check the logcat section? Sorry im kinda new to this

Answer (score 1):

Press shift button twice. A dialog box with search bar will appear, then type Logcat(Alt + 6). A window will which will look like this :-
[image]
Connect the phone and make sure you are able to see your phone on the top left corner. Still not solved your problem then you can type:

```
adb kill-server
```

and then

```
adb start-server
```

Or try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)